# Como verificar se o assento está livre e se não estiver pedir para o usuário digitar novamente inserindo um 'X' no espaço ocupado?

Tags: c

Preciso que o usuário insira onde ele quer se sentar informando a fileira e a coluna que deseja, caso o usuário escolha a posição **0-1** o programa irá cadastrar e gravar em um arquivo txt posterior mente essa informação, e entrará em um *looping* para efetuar o cadastro de um novo usuário, onde ele irá digitar qual a posição que deseja e se caso ele digite uma posição onde já está ocupada por outro usuário o programa **não aceitará** colocando um **X** no lugar para demonstrar que está ocupado.

Segue o código...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    printf("\n \nEscolha seu assento: \n\n");

    int m, n, fileira, assento;
    int lugares[10][16];

    for(m=1;m<10;m++){
        for(n=1;n<16;n++){
            printf("[%d- %d]", m, n);
        }

        printf("\n");   
    }

    printf("\nFileira desejada: ");
    scanf("%d",&fileira);
    printf("Assento desejado: ");
    scanf("%d",&assento);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Como você usa valores 0 e 1, não faz sentido usar um inteiro. Você poderia usar um `bool` sendo `true` ocupado e `false` não. O loop deve começar do 0 também ao invés de 1 como esta fazendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que já está quase terminado então.
Basta adicionar este código já feito em um while e criar uma váriavel booleana de controle para encerrar o loop.
Não sei se entendi como você administrará os lugares, mas vou supor que seja 0 para vago e 1 para ocupado. No seu for então adicione:

```
lugares[m][n] = 0;
```

Então faça o loop:

```
bool encerrar = false;

while (!encerrar)
{
    //seu código sem as declarações das váriaveis.

    if (lugares[fileira][assento] == 1)
        printf("Posicao Ocupada!\n");
    else
        lugares[fileira][assento] = 1;
}
```

Acho que aí tem um bom começo para continuar..

Comment: `bool` subentende o uso de `stdbool.h`. Parece me importante você mencionar isso na resposta.

Comment: Eu não entendi o código direito em si, teria como colocar a parte que eu desenvolvi junto com a inclusão já? Desculpe sou meio leigo ainda nesse quesito de programação.